# PHP - How do you randomize the last 4 digits of a phone number

Tags: php, random, numbers, phone-number

How would you randomize the last 4 digits of a phone number?

Given:

```
$phone = '000-000-0000';
```

Results would be:

```
$phone = '000-000-1943';
```

where **1943** is a random number

Can this be done in a single line command using something like preg...

or some other one line command ?

Comment: @Michael Berkowski I am not assigning phone numbers. It is actually used to assign a random part number that looks similar to a phone number. The phone number format is an analogy that is easier to understand for this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) is good for extracting *n* characters from the beginning/end of string; [`rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) can be used to generate a random number, [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) can be used to format a number. Put all three functions together:

```
$phone = '000-000-0000';
$phone = sprintf('%s%04d', substr($phone, 0, -4), rand(0, 9999));
echo $phone;
// 000-000-2317
```

Comment: this yeilds 0951 (4 digits)

Comment: just need to replace the last 4 digits with random numbers and output the entire modified phone number

Comment: What exactly is this piece of code doing? Did you test the output before complaining?

Comment: i was not complaining. I did run the code. the result should be a 10 digit revised number with the last 4 digits randomized

Comment: Confirmed working as OP requested. 10 digits output with randomised last 4 digits.

Comment: @Salman A Actually it works well, i had a type error on the 1st try, but fixed it... Thank you

Answer (score 4):

```
$phone = preg_replace_callback('/\d{4}$/', function($m) {
    return str_pad(mt_rand(0, 9999), 4, '0');
}, $phone);
```

Comment: +1 more complex than it needs to be with preg, but meh, it does the job.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) method together with the [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) method.

```
$phone = '000-000-'.str_pad(rand(0,9999), 4, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$phone = '000-000-0000';
$phone=explode('-',$phone);
$phone[2]=str_pad(rand(0,9999), 4, 0);
$phone=implode('-', $phone);
```